# SharePoint document library public access

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there any way for making a SharePoint document library available for public access. I want the access a document in a SharePoint library using the link for the document in the "copy link" button without any authentication. Is there any possible way to do it.
I am currently intending to do is to paste the SharePoint document link in a browser and without authentication(without user needing to log in) able to access it

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [solution](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site). Set anonymous access to web application and follow the guide how to set up access to entire website or library.